# Make a 'T' panel in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I am making an application, and I want to have a layout with the shape of a 'T'. So there will be a top section, that spans the entire width of the panel, and then underneath should contain a left and a right panel, again so the application is in the form of a 'T' shape.

The top part should contain flowing buttons, which I know how to do.
But the left/right sections should be separate content panes. Any helps would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post a short, simple example (emphasis on short) that shows what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
// a border layout can create a 'T panel' effect
ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
ui.setBackground(Color.RED);

// I would prefer to use a JToolBar for this ..
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
// usually unnecessary, but to show the 'T' effect
buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);
ui.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
buttonPanel.add(new JButton("NORTH"));

JLabel labelCenter = new JLabel("CENTER");
labelCenter.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 100, 20, 100));
ui.add(labelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel contentLeft = new JPanel();
ui.add(contentLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
contentLeft.add(new JLabel("LEFT"));

JPanel contentRight = new JPanel();
ui.add(contentRight, BorderLayout.EAST);
contentRight.add(new JLabel("RIGHT"));
```